# SettingWithCopyWarning with datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert '`ad_created`' column to datetime object but getting `SettingWithCopyWarning` error. I know it has been discussed here many times but somehow I can't figure it out in my case. I spent quite a few hours researching it already.

```
clean_autos['ad_created'] = pd.to_datetime(clean_autos['ad_created'])
```

Error Message

```
{/dataquest/system/env/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  if __name__ == '__main__':}
```

I tried it with .loc but still getting error

```
clean_autos.loc[:,'ad_created'] = pd.to_datetime(clean_autos['ad_created'])
```

Error Message

```
/dataquest/system/env/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:537: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self.obj[item] = s
```

The main goal I am trying to achieve is that, to convert `clean_autos['ad_created'] & clean_autos['last_seen']` to datetime object,
and then do some subtraction to find out how long on average the add remains online.

```
clean_autos['ad_created']

0        2016-03-26 00:00:00
1        2016-04-04 00:00:00
2        2016-03-26 00:00:00
3        2016-03-12 00:00:00


clean_autos['ad_created'].describe()
count                   46712
unique                     74
top       2016-04-03 00:00:00
freq                     1829
Name: ad_created, dtype: object
```

Comment: A lot of time time this happens when clean_autos is a dataframe created from a subset or filter of a larger dataframe.  Use `clean_autos = df[filter].copy()`

Comment: can you share a few rows of data in clean_autos['ad_created']. Not sure why you would get this unless there is some challenge with the data itself

Comment: Same thoughts here Joe, I don't see any problem with data or actual code. 
The main goal I am trying to achieve is that, to convert clean_autos['ad_created'] & clean_autos['last_seen'] to datetime object, and then do some subtraction to find out how long on average the add remains online.                        

`clean_autos['ad_created']  
0        2016-03-26 00:00:00
1        2016-04-04 00:00:00
2        2016-03-26 00:00:00
3        2016-03-12 00:00:00`

Comment: @Joe I edited the main post, and provided the details you asked for. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out, I used the `copy() method` for copying the set instead of `using = operator` for copying set.

This was `clean_autos['ad_created'] = pd.to_datetime(clean_autos['ad_created'])` throwing `SettingWithCopyWarning`. I ignored the warning, and kept working but the end result wasn't correct.

I first used `Python Set copy()` method `clean_autos_final = clean_autos.copy()` , and then changed it to datetime object, worked like a charm.

```
clean_autos_final['ad_created']=pd.to_datetime(clean_autos_final['ad_created'])
```

Thanks everyone :)